# Modify maven test output in console

Tags: maven, junit, console

Firing `mvn clean test` 
prints this:
[image: Maven console output]

Due to some conditions I skip tests dynamically.

However, I'd like to print the cause for skipping to the console, like it's done for failing tests:
[image]

is there any way to archieve this?

Alternativly, how could I properly log it, so it's still recognizable between all the other logs?

I'm using `log4j` for logging. Any Ideas?

Comment: How are you skipping the tests?

Comment: @khmarbaise with Assumptions.